# Engine configuration for lander

Tags: mars, landing, engine-design, lander, stability

**Which is a more stable lander design:**

1.Single central engine.

2.Multiple engines located near the corners

Following is the design for Tianwen-1, the Chinese Mars lander:

[image]

And following is the design for InSight, the NASA Mars lander:

[image]

At the first glance it seems that a single engine design may be a little more unstable than the multi engine counterpart. I am confused about what is taken in to account for the placement of thrusters/engines...

**What are the various parameters taken into consideration while designing the engine configuration/number for a lander (moon / Mars, taking atmosphere into account)?**

Comment: Great question, not long ago I asked a question about Viking, which had 3 engines.

Comment: slightly related: [What is the purpose and necessity of this giant structure being used in tests of China's Mars lander?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39901/12102)

Comment: This is pure speculation, so I will not post as an answer: One engine is probably simpler, but with three, you can adjust the throttle on each to help steer.

Comment: There's several tradeoffs, it's more than just a matter of stability. With multiple separated engines, you need fast, precise throttling to keep things under control. This arrangement will be more suited for a squat and wide lander, with each engine pointing well away from the center of mass. With a single central engine (or a compact cluster for redundancy), you can't use differential thrust and need gimbaling instead. This arrangement is better suited for a tall lander with high center of gravity, but might still be used for a squat one due to not needing as precise throttle control.

Comment: I suspect also that multiple engines may be chosen to dissipate the exhaust as to not carve out the surface of the moon/planet.